# Is Battleworld part of All-New, All-Different Marvel?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars

So, I was wondering, as me being new to the whole comic world, I want to join it, but it just seems so overwhelming! I figured that Secret Wars would be a good jumping in place, however, I see several titles under the Battleworld title and then I see the secret wars logo underneath it, and then there is All-New, All-Different Marvel.  I know Battleworld is a patchwork of alternate realities, but is All-New, All-Different Marvel in Battleworld and does Battleworld still exist?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-fi Stack Exchange! Great first question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Battleworld](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Battleworld_(Latverion)) still exists in the All-New, All-Different Marvel, having collapsed and later been reformed by Maetsro via the power of the Iso-Sphere

Now it is guarded by the [Civil Warriors](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Civil_Warriors_(Earth-15513)), but it is very much out there, somewhere in the multiverse.

Comment: _having collapsed and later been reformed by Maetsro via the power of the Iso-Sphere_... welcome to comics Mew Two!!